# Swift - Enum in UIView shows up as nil when set from other ViewController

Tags: swift, firebase, enums, swift5

I'm having trouble with this Firebase application. I have an enum inside a UIView that shows up as nil even when I set it in `viewDidLoad()`. The UIView is just a header view, with the enum serving through a `switch` statement to determine which button to display for which user type. Here's the code for the UIView (shortened to just show necessary code for readability):

```
enum HeaderViewOptions: Int {
    case partner
    case client
}

class HeaderView: UIView {

    var options: HeaderViewOptions!

    //...

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        //...

        switch options {
        case .partner:
            addSubview(addServiceButton)
            //...
        case .client:
            addSubview(searchButton)
            //...
        case .none:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Here's where the series of functions and variables in order inside the ViewController that set the `options` variable:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    checkUser()
}

func checkUser() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil {
        //...
    } else {
        configure()
    }
}

func configure() {
    //...
    fetchUserData()
    //...
}

func fetchUserData() {
    guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    Services.shared.fetchUserData(uid: currentUid) { user in
        self.user = user
    }
}

private var user: User? {
    didSet {
        if user?.accountType == .partner {
            headerView.options = .partner
        } else {
            headerView.options = .client
        }
    }
}
```

The `accountType` property for the `User` object has the same enum options as the `HeaderView` class.

Comment: actually you need to post more code where you are adding buttons on the basis of this enum ... i doubt this issue is related to async call ... you access option before setting them ...

Comment: Could variable user be returning nil and not the enum?

Comment: @jawadAli All I do after the `addSubview(button)` is set their constraints. I guess what I'm trying to ask is how to wait to instantiate the `HeaderView` UIView until the user is set, so the options is set and it can properly be configured.

Comment: @purebreadd That's odd, I printed out `user` after the `fetchUserData()` method call and it did show up as nil. I need to look into that.

Comment: I would guess the user is not logged in to firebase yet. You need to Authenticate users before you can access their uid. Having a user's data in your database, and having a user authenticated/logged in to Firebase are 2 separate functions fyi

Answer (score 1):

Update your async function

```
func fetchUserData() {
    guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    Services.shared.fetchUserData(uid: currentUid) {[weak self] user in
        self?.user = user
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self?.configureButtonsInView() // add buttons here
        }
    }
}
```